# Java creating a font using images

Tags: java

I wanted to make a custom font for a game I am trying to make but I want to separate all of the characters into different files. So far, I have made all of the character images and have managed to make it print out the correct characters that I want to print. The problem is that when I use certain characters such as lowercase characters and J's the alignment is wrong. I have no idea how to go about fixing this. The other problem is I need to be able to get the width/height of a string using this font, but to do this I also need to resize the letters to the right size.

This is my code for the font:

```
package org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.gui.font.image;

import java.util.LinkedList;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.render.basic.BasicRenderer;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.core.render.colour.Colour;
import org.simplecorporation.myengine.utils.file.FileUtils;


public class ImageFolderFont {

/* The font */
public LinkedList<ImageLetter> letters;

/* The font size */
public double size;

/* The constructor of the font */
public ImageFolderFont(String folder , String imageFormat , boolean inFolder , double size) {
    //Load the font

    //Create the letters linked list
    this.letters = new LinkedList<ImageLetter>();

    //The file text
    LinkedList<String> fileText = FileUtils.read(folder + "/font.txt");

    //Load all of the images in the font
    for (int a = 0; a < fileText.size(); a++) {
        //Split the current line
        String[] split = fileText.get(a).split(" ");
        //Create the letter
        ImageLetter letter = new ImageLetter(split[0].charAt(0) , folder + "/" + split[1] , imageFormat , inFolder);
        //Add the letter to the letters
        this.letters.add(letter);
    }

    //Set the size
    this.size = size;
}

/* The method that renders the font */
public void render(String text , double x , double y) {
    //Enable blending
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
    GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA , GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    //Loop though the text
    for (int a = 0; a < text.length(); a++) {
        //Check if the current letter is a space
        if (text.charAt(a) == ' ') {
            x += this.size / 2;
        } else {
            //Set the colour, get the letter and render the letter image
            BasicRenderer.setColour(Colour.WHITE);
            ImageLetter letter = this.getLetter(text.charAt(a));
            //The width and height
            double width = 0;
            double height = 0;
            //Check the size
            if ((letter.getWidth() / letter.getHeight()) == 1) {
                width = size * (letter.getWidth() / letter.getHeight() * 1.5);
                height = size * (letter.getWidth() / letter.getHeight());
            } else {
                width = size * (letter.getHeight() / letter.getWidth());
                height = size * (letter.getHeight() / letter.getWidth());
            }
            BasicRenderer.renderImage(letter , x , y ,  width , height);
            //Add to the x position
            x += width / 2;
        }
    }
}

/* The method to get the width of a string */
public double getWidth(String text) {
    //The width of the text
    double width = 0;
    //Loop though the text
    for (int a = 0; a < text.length(); a++) {
        //Get the letter
        ImageLetter letter = this.getLetter(text.charAt(a));
        //Add to the width
        width += size * (letter.getHeight() / letter.getWidth()) + 4;
    }
    //Return the width
    return width;
}

/* The method to get the height of a string */
public double getHeight(String text) {
    //The height of the text
    double height = 0;
    //Loop though the text
    for (int a = 0; a < text.length(); a++) {
        //Get the letter
        ImageLetter letter = this.getLetter(text.charAt(a));
        //Check if the letters size is bigger
        if (letter.getWidth() * (letter.getHeight() / size) > height)
            height = letter.getWidth() * (letter.getHeight() / size);
    }
    //Return the height
    return height;
}

/* The method that returns a letter based on a char */
public ImageLetter getLetter(char character) {
    //The letter
    ImageLetter letter = this.letters.get(0);

    //Loop though the letters
    for (int a = 0; a < this.letters.size(); a ++) {
        //Check if the current letter is the right one
        if (this.letters.get(a).character == character) {
            //Set the letter
            letter = this.letters.get(a);
            //Exit the loop
            break;
        }
    }

    //Return the letter
    return letter;
}

}
```

ImageLetter is an image with a char variable that contains the character it represents.

Image: https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/3252552/1103273/041ac464-1898-11e3-8b53-1e81573eec97.png

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typography is a rich subject. Each letter in your custom "font" should define the y-position of the [base line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_%28typography%29). The base line is basically the definition of where the bottom of the letters should lie. Most letters lie completely on top of the base line, but some, like j, and y, have parts called "descenders" that extend below the base line. Glyphs of your font should not be rendered so that the top of the letters coincide, but so that the base lines coincide.

An easy alternative could be adding enough whitespace to the top of the images of the letters so that all of them extend from the top of the line ("ascender height") to the bottom of the letter. That way all letters would appear to have the same base line.